# how to use chakra provider and material UI together in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, chakra-ui

We are working on project of clone of flipkart.com.We are working on team.so we have distributed our works. One of guy worked on landing page with material UI and i am working on product page with chakra ui but after merging app is not working and producing unfamiliar error.

So, provide some solution so we can make our presentation.

in index.js i have written this code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import FlipkartStore from './Components/Redux_Implementation/Store/Store';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ChakraProvider, extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react';

const muiTheme = createTheme();
const theme = extendTheme();

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={FlipkartStore}>
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme} >
    <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
    </ChakraProvider>
  </Provider>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))

reportWebVitals();
```

its showing this error
[image: showing error if i am wrap]

if am removing chakra provider page is working but my product page css is not working

[image: without chakra provider]

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
  <ChakraProvider theme={chakraTheme}>
    ...
  </ChakraProvider>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `ChakraProvider` only for your page as needed.

If you are using React Router. You could wrap the provider only for your path.

Example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/products">
    <ChakraProvider> /*  wrap only for your products page */
      <Products />
    </ChakraProvider>
  </Route>
  <Route path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your route inside ChakraProvider.

```
<Switch>
      <Route path='/your_path'>
           <ChakraProvider>
                <YourComponent />
           </ChakraProvider>
      </Route>
      <Route path ='/your_path_2' element={<YourOtherComponent />} />
</Switch>
```

Just wrap your route inside the route.

Answer (score 0):

The component you want to use you can wrap it in chakra provider.

```
<Route path='/'>
   <ChakraProvider>
        <Component you want />
   </ChakraProvider>
 </Route>
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically the best way to use both chakra-ui and mui is to merge their provided theme and give both of their providers the same theme like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import AutoComplete from "@material-ui/core/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { deepmerge } from "@material-ui/utils";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { ChakraProvider, extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const muiTheme = createMuiTheme();
const chakraTheme = extendTheme();

//the important part
const theme = deepmerge(chakraTheme, muiTheme);

console.log({ chakraTheme, muiTheme });

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <ChakraProvider theme={theme} resetCSS>
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
          <AutoComplete
            id="combo-box-demo"
            options={[{ title: "a" }, { title: "b" }, { title: "c" }]}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
            )}
          />
        </div>
      </ChakraProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```